# Scroll to middle of selected item of recyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to be able to automatically scroll inside an horizontal RecyclerView and put the selected item in middle of the screen

[image]

In the attached image the selected item is "my apps" so i want to automatically scroll the RV so that "my apps" will show on center of screen

I know How to scroll to speciffic position:

```
linearLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(2, 20);
```

How can i get the relative position of the item inside the recyclerView so i can scroll to it?

My RecyclerView def:

```
CategoriesAdapter adapter = new CategoriesAdapter(list, this);
    catagoriesRV.setAdapter(adapter);
    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    catagoriesRV.setLayoutManager(llm);
```

Answer (score 0):

add

```
var isSelected=false
```

into your data model,
when user click on any item, set

```
 list.map{
   it.isSelected=false
 }
 item.isSelected=true
    
recyclerView.scrollToPosition((item?.indexOfFirst { it.isSelected }?: 0))
```